# MVC EnableCors can we be sure of the origin?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

i have read an article on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api).

They use Oauth2 password grand_type in javascript ajax call to a WebApi.

This is secure if we don't allow CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing). But i wish to allow an other website to use this api with auth2.

My question is, **how can i be sure they'r not someone posting to my server**.
Some one can pretend it's on this website (Like changing host file in "System32\drivers\etc\hosts" or local dns)

**Is the EnableCors attribute double check in browser and on the host for the validity of the host or it's a browser thing?**

The other website is only javascript, no server-side like asp or php ...

If you can provide security documentation for Cors, it will be very nice.

Tank you.

**EDIT:**
I'm not asking how to use it. I'm asking if the alowed host can be bypassed.

As the call are made by ajax on javascript, it's the client ip i get when a request is made, i get the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) to validate on server-side, but i don't trust it because the client can change it.

I'm asking if i can trust the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, if the server validate it or if it's only for the browser, bypassing security rules in the browser itself. And if i can't trust it, is there a way to have a trusted origin request.

Comment: You can create a whitelist of allowed IPs that can access your web api

Comment: can you provide documentation please?
This can answer the question eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is not about authentication...it's about collaboration.

It is the way of helping other sites to not get into troubles.
By default client's browser prohibits cross origin requests. But it can ask your server: "Hey, guy, don't you mind if client code originating from that server gets data from you?"
If you don't enable CORS for any site by default then client code cannot read data from your server. But when developer deliberately introduces such behavior he can ask you for that explicit permission.

CORS is the way to protect third party, not your data.

After request is allowed, it then must be authenticated and authorized as usual unless you don't care =)

Thus there is no need for verifying origin claims. Moreover, this origin information MUSTN'T participate in authentication/authorization information. If you really need to authenticate requesting party then other server MUST authenticate itself against your service and only after that serve data to its clients thus working as a proxy.

Comment: Tanks! this is very clear. I have to change the way i have to do it, making an oauth like facebook do with the connect method and not using the grand_type=password.I will use Authorization with refresh_token.

Answer (score 2):

Extending my comment.

Here's an action filter that restricts access only for all IP addresses except for specific ones:

```
public class RestrictIpAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _allowedIPs;
    public RestrictIpAttribute(string[] allowedIPs)
    {
        _allowedIPs = allowedIPs;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var context = actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as System.Web.HttpContextBase;
        string userIP = context.Request.UserHostAddress;

        if (_allowedIPs.All(ip => ip != userIP))
        {
            actionContext.Response =
               new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
               {
                   Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized IP Address")
               };
        }
    }
}
```

You can put the allowed IP addresses into database, config file or wherever you want it.

*As a side note, this solution is not connected directly to allowing CORS*

Comment: Tank you for the action filter example. As i can see, it's the client browser who make the request, in ajax. So i cant use your solution. but +1 for a good example ;-) I have updated my question.

Comment: Afaik, this header only applies for the browser and is not validated by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following configuration in your web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://www.myapp.com" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i dont have asked how to use it. I have update my question. Excuse me if it's not clear, i'm french, my English is not perfect...